# Monitoring SQL Agent Service on Windows Server with Nagios

Tags: monitoring, nagios, sql-agent

I'm looking for guidance on how to configure Nagios to monitor the SQL Agent service (SQL Server Agent) on Windows Server. Specifically, I want to ensure that Nagios can detect and alert me if the SQL Agent service is not running or encounters any issues.

I have successfully set up Nagios to monitor my SQL Server instances running on Windows Server. However, I now want to extend this monitoring to include the SQL Agent service.

Comment: Hello, this site is about programming and not suitable for general how-to questions about software.